# How to use INDIRECT with INDEX-MATCH in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula

```
=INDEX(tblWeek1[Area],MATCH($P6,tblWeek1[Leader],0))
```

is working correctly where `$P6` is a leader name and an Area for that leader is returned.

However, I want to replace the table names with the value from a cell that will contain a chosen table name (I have multiple table for different weeks). But,

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A1"&"[Area]"),MATCH($P6,(INDIRECT("A1")&"[Leader]"),0))
```

Does not work where A1 contains `"tblWeek1"`, even though
`=INDIRECT("A1")&"[Area]"` by itself correctly returns:
`"tblWeek1[Area]"`

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Basically you have made mistake in double quote `"A"`. It will be `Indirect(A1 & "[Area]"...…` See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A1 & "[Area]"),MATCH(G3,INDIRECT(A1 & "[Leader]"),0))
```

[image]